# take a row_number in delete query with where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have follwing DBTable:

[image]

In this database there is question stored in bith english and spanish language.

For Language=1 is English and 2 is spanish translation of the same question.

I am displaying only a English question in gridview for particular kiskid

To display data in gridview i am using following query:

> select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QMID) AS SrNo,question,kioskid 
>   from QuestionMaster where Language=1 and KioskID='K1'

This query gives me following data:

[image]

Now i wanted to make delete query from the data in above grid such that when i delete "may i come in?" i.e. SrNo=1 then its relevant spanish should also get deleted.

As i have generated srno by taking row_number , (its not in DB) its creating me a problem to delete next equivalent spanish record to that question.

I tried using row_number in where of delete query, but its not giving me results.

Please help me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter its mentioned in first image(actual snap of DB) eg. for may i come in,,, its mere do entrar,,for both records QMID is same

Comment: How have you tried to delete a record, what is the parameter? Do you want to delete by `SrNo`, `QMID` or `Question` or a combination?

Comment: direct parameter that i can get is SrNo,Question And Kioskid,,,but srno is of no use since its not actual record in DB,, question and kioskid can get repeated @TimSchmelter

Comment: You should normalize your table and add a `Question` table. Then a relation table between `Language` and `Question`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i just wanted to delete question from DB Eg. may i come in? and next record to it, i.e. mere do entrar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't this work?

```
delete from QuestionMaster
    where Language = 2 and KioskID = 'K1' and QMID = 1;
```

If it is because you don't have `QMID`, you can do:

```
delete from QuestionMaster
    where Language = 2 and KioskID = 'K1' and
          QMID in (select QMID
                   from QuestionMaster
                   where Language = 1 and question = 'May I come In'
                  )
```

I'm not sure what the `row_number()` is doing.

EDIT:

If you want to delete both (all?) records based on the QMID, then remove the language condition in the `where` for `delete`:

```
delete from QuestionMaster
    where KioskID = 'K1' and
          QMID in (select QMID
                   from QuestionMaster
                   where Language = 1 and question = 'May I come In'
                  )
```

Comment: by this only spanish record is getting deleted, i wanted to delete english record also

Comment: i added and language=2 in subquery (select QMID from QuestionMaster....) , but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just retrieve the QMID from the database and use that one to delete the question in all languages?

Comment: A little of both i guess. From what i see he's got an ID (QMID) for every question, so I was wondering why he wouldn't just use that to delete his question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use ROW_NUMBER ? Wouldn't `Select * from QuestionMaster where Language = 1` do the same job.

As would `delete from QuestionMaster where QMID = 1` ?

Comment: I dont want to display QMID in grid, just i have been told to display serialnumber to each shown question by ROW_Number

Comment: So don't display it ? You can hide columns in grids.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that requirement either. It is not good design to intentionally misuse relational data.

Comment: That's right - I think this is a really good example of starting with a bad design, then everything after that point involves workarounds and fixes. I obviously don't know the circumstances etc. etc. but adding answers and solutions will only extend the problems I think ...

Answer (score 0):

You should could the `QMID` in your query:

```
select
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QMID) AS SrNo
    ,QMID
    ,question
    ,kioskid
from QuestionMaster
where Language=1 and KioskID='K1'
```

Then create a binding object in C#/VB

```
public class Question
{
    [DisplayName("Serial Number")]
    public int SrNo { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public int QMID { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public int KioskId { get; set; }
}
```

The [`BrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) will indicate that the column should not be displayed in your DataGridView.

That way your deletes are easier.

```
delete from QuestionMaster where QMID = @QMID
```

Comment: Thanx,but,If i was allowed to enter  QMID in query (gridview) , the job would have been lot easier. I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: So go back to whoever told you that you can't and explain the error of their ways. Maybe be a bit more diplomatic than that. Out of interest what is the reasoning behind it ?